# Printer Server Disconnecting Users when doing driver update

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-printer

We have a print Server on Windows Server 2012 R2. When I update an old printer object with a new print driver. Other printers seem to disconnect only for some users, not all, on their local computer. And then need to delete / re-install the printer in order to download the old driver again to make it work. They get pass the "Do you trust this Driver". And then everything works like normal. The other printer are Canon printer too.

Printer:Canon 7570i
Driver: CNLB0UA64.inf From the UFRII_V30.30_Set-up_x64

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier method to bypass that problem is to use driver signed/certified by Microsoft, those will not prompt the user.

If you cant use signed driver then you have to configure point&print gpo settings. In computer/policies/admin template/printers/point and print restriction, select disable

Comment: But updating a 1 driver should not cause users to disconnect on a printer that i didn't update. Printers are using different drivers according to their model type.

Comment: @cocominion that mean your driver is used on others printqueues, please check

Comment: Hi, i see what this does now. Ok thanks for the advice looks promising.